# Set Material-UI tab active based on visited route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, material-ui

In my new react-redux app (I'm a newbie to react), I'm using [Material-UI](http://www.material-ui.com/) and have added material-ui tabs on my web app. The tabs are intended to change the URL upon selection which I achieved using the following piece of code.

```
function handleActive(tab) {
    browserHistory.push(tab.props['data-route']);
}
```

I want my tabs to show selected tab indicator when I visit the routes manually instead of clicking on the tabs. Which I'm right now not able to figure out. Can anyone suggest me a way to do that either by react or redux? Let me know, If I'm not clear in my question.

**UPDATE**

Code in my components `render()`. There is nothing else in component.

```
render() {
    function handleActive(tab) {
        browserHistory.push(tab.props['data-route']);
    }

    return (
        <Paper>
            <Toolbar className="navbar">
                <ToolbarGroup>
                    <Link to="/" style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
                        <ToolbarTitle style={this.styles.title} text="Test App" />
                    </Link>
                </ToolbarGroup>
                <ToolbarGroup className="tab-container">
                    <Tabs className="tabs">
                        <Tab data-route="/" onActive={handleActive} className="tab" label="Route A" />
                        <Tab data-route="/routeB" onActive={handleActive} className="tab" label="Route B" />
                        <Tab data-route="/routeC" onActive={handleActive} className="tab" label="Route C" />
                        <Tab data-route="/routeD" onActive={handleActive} className="tab" label="Route D" />
                    </Tabs>
                </ToolbarGroup>
            </Toolbar>
        </Paper>
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you post entire code of your component?

Comment: @RandomUser Added the code.

Answer (score 7):

I doubt if parsing url is a great idea. Maybe it's better to control tab index from router dispatching action in `onEnter` prop of `<Route>`?

Let's say you have 2 routes:

```
<Route path='sign_in' component={AuthenticationWrapper} onEnter={() => { store.dispatch(changeTab(0)) }} />
<Route path='sign_up' component={AuthenticationWrapper} onEnter={() => { store.dispatch(changeTab(1)) }} />
```

Action creator:

```
changeTab = (index) => {
  return { type: AUTH_TAB_CHANGE, index }
}
```

Reducer:

```
authTab = (state = 0, action = {}) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case AUTH_TAB_CHANGE:
      return action.index
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Component:

```
class AuthenticationWrapper extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.handleSignIn = this.handleActive.bind(this, '/sign_in')
    this.handleSignUp = this.handleActive.bind(this, '/sign_up')
  }

  handleActive(url) {
    browserHistory.push(url)
  }

  render() {
    const { authTab, changeTab } = this.props

    return (
      <Tabs index={authTab} onChange={changeTab}>
        <Tab label='Sign In' onActive={this.handleSignIn}>
          <SignInForm />
        </Tab>
        <Tab label='Sign Up' onActive={this.handleSignUp}>
          <SignUpForm />
        </Tab>
      </Tabs>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ authTab }) => {
  return {
    authTab
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  changeTab,
})(AuthenticationWrapper)
```

Such approach will work both with visiting different urls and changing tabs by clicking on them without refreshing page.

Answer (score 3):

Although there are few ways to do it, Since you're using React Component Class,
You can add `componentWillMount`

```
componentWillMount() {

  let urlPath = window.location.pathname;
  let currentTab = urlPath.split('/').pop();
  // you can add more validations here
  this.setState({ activeTab: currentTab || 'default' });

}
```

And in your `render` method, change `<Tabs className="tabs">` to

```
<Tabs
  className="tabs"
  value={this.state.activeTab}
  >
    <Tab value="default" data-route="/" onActive={handleActive} className="tab" label="Route A" />
    <Tab value="routeC" data-route="/routeC" onActive={handleActive} className="tab" label="Route C" />
    ...
```

I don't know if this is how we're supposed to set the `value` for the `Tab`.., But play around with it.

And it should work.

I have used `setState` here instead of `redux`, As there's nothing wrong in using Component state as long as this is the only component which needs to know which tab is currently active., You can easily change it to use `redux` though.

Comment: I doubt if parsing url is a great idea. Maybe it's better to control tab index from router dispatching action in `onEnter` prop of `<Route>`? See my code below.

Comment: @ktaras While you might be correct, this is **not a bad idea** either., This all depends on users requirements. If this is the only component that cares about current tab then there's no need to save it in `redux store` and also no need to use `react-router` middleware as this will add to  the component's dependency, User can easily use `redux`, `component state`, `middlewares`, `pure functions` or combination of all.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you need to do a couple of things to make sure that you can catch url in the page where tabs are in. Here is what you should do:

- When you render your highest component, make sure you have `<Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />` rendered in the div id of your index html. It seems you are doing this since you have browserHistory working.
- In you routes, make sure you have nested routes so that in the parent component, you pass this.props.children so that you have /path/to/comp in the children reflected in the url. Again, you probably have this set up as well.
- Now, you will need to add value to your Tabs and Tab component as explained in here http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/tabs. Value will specify which Tab is active depending on the one selected for Tabs so `<Tabs className="tabs" value={this is where your this.props.params.name_of_changing_route}>` or in case you have react-router 2.4.0, you can wrap your component with withRouter then you can have access to params, location and route.